# jQuery: Bind Custom Event to Pre-Defined Function

Tags: jquery, swipe

I've seen lots of posts and questioned on binding a custom event using jQuery but all the appropriate examples I could find have the function inline (defined as part of the bind).  I'm trying to call a pre-defined function from a custom bind.  To explain what I'm doing I currently have custom events bound to a HTML element like this:

```
<div id="page" ontouchstart="touchStart(event,'swipeBox');" ontouchend="touchEnd(event, leftSwipe, rightSwipe, downSwipe, upSwipe);" ontouchmove="touchMove(event);" ontouchcancel="touchCancel(event);">
```

I'd like to do that in jQuery so I can control the binding based on other events but I can't for the life of me get it to work, I know have the following working in terms of firing the touch events but for some reason the swiping functions just aren't working:

```
$('#page').bind('touchstart', function(event){touchStart(event, 'page')});
$('#page').bind('touchend', function(event){touchEnd(event, '/overview/', '/contact/', '/contact/', '/')});
$('#page').bind('touchmove', function(event){touchMove(event)});
$('#page').bind('touchcancel', function(event){alert('touchCancel'); touchCancel(event)});
```

I have an example of the swiping working correctly using the same JS except the binding is done in the HTML (as above) which can be seen here: http://sr.spark-storm.com/about/

Then my attempt to bind using jQuery (same JS library for the swiping) is here: http://sr.spark-storm.com/

As you can see they are **very** simple pages - barely any markup to them really.

Comment: Did you try this way? $('#page').bind('ontouchstart', function(){touchStart('ontouchstart', 'swipeBox')});

Comment: Hi Pavan,
Thanks for the tip, I used that format and I now no longer get an error but the functions are not being called:
 $('#page').bind('ontouchstart', function(){touchStart(event, 'page')});
 $('#page').bind('ontouchend', function(){touchEnd(event, leftSwipe, rightSwipe, downSwipe, upSwipe)}); 
 $('#page').bind('ontouchmove', function(){touchMove(event)}); 
 $('#page').bind('ontouchcancel', function(){touchCancel(event)}); 

To clarify what I'm doing - I have 'swipe' detection on my website using this library: http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/

It works find when I being via HTML

Comment: `function(event){touchStart(...)}` to actually pick up the `event` object jQuery passes on to the callback in `bind`

Comment: Hi all, In the end I used a different library for the swiping (http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library) and that made it all fairly painless, plus it was smaller as it uses jQuery (which was already loaded in the page anyway).
Thanks for all the assistance!